# Getting segfault on logout

Tags: kernel, release-hera

Using ElementaryOS 5.1 Hera, Kernel 4.15.0-72-generic.

I recently changed my username on my account and its caused a strange issue - on logout, a segmentation fault in libgio-2.0.so triggers, and the screen defaults to an Ubuntu 18.04 theme. If I log back in, the system freezes for 30 seconds before I'm able to do anything.

A snippet of the kernel logs on logout and login:

```
[   54.557029] show_signal_msg: 17 callbacks suppressed
[   54.557030] io.elementary.c[1678]: segfault at f ip 00007f1ccbe092f3 sp 00007ffd1b75a5a0 error 4 in libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.4[7f1ccbd67000+195000]
[   54.557766] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   80.074395] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

I've done a quick search on the fault, and it seems to be a known but fixed error with Cinnamon (which I'm pretty sure I'm not using). Are there any known fixes for this?

I have tried:

- reinstalling elementary-desktop
- reinstalling lightdm
- reinstalling gir1.2-gio-2.0
- (re)installing libid3tag0 libsox-fmt-mp3 vnstat vnstati

to no avail.

Thanks for the help!